# Need assistance with leak-finder.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Hey so I am trying to use the leak-finder.js library. I followed all the instructions from http://code.google.com/p/leak-finder-for-javascript/.

I tried to use the following command in the console of chrome

```
goog.Disposable.ENABLE_MONITORING=true
```

but am getting the following error

```
ReferenceError: goog is not defined
```

So I tried to import the Closure library, but cannot seem to import it onto chrome and it seems that it has been deprecated for Firefox. 
So any suggestions as to what I should do.